# What is the value of x in this diagram?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, trigonometric-series

[image]

So I'm pretty familiar with SOH-CAH-TOA but this question in particular looks a bit different and I'm not sure how to go about it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use $\tan 54^\circ$ to find the altitude of the largest triangle, and then from there use $\cos 23^\circ$ to find $x$.

Comment: The only thing different from your usual SOH-CAH-TOA problems is that you have to apply SOH-CAH-TOA _twice._ There are two right triangles explicitly drawn in the figure, so solve one at a time according to the previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by finding the middle side length.$$\tan(54^o)=\frac{z}{17}$$$$z=17\tan(54^o)$$$$\cos(23^o)=\frac zx$$$$x=\frac z{\cos(23^o)}=\frac{17\tan(54^o)}{\cos(23^o)}$$